# Moving 50GB of data from one MySql server to another

Tags: mysql, database

I need to move some 50GB of data, spread around over 30 schemas, from one server to another.

I know about the process of exporting a schema to `sql` then sending the file vie `ftp` (for example) to the new server and importing it.

I also know I can connect directly through `MySqlWorkbench` or on the command line and save do it directly. But for 50GB and 30 schemas this would still take days.

Is there any way to make the process shorter?

Comment: You can try using ETL tools.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5933/5203

Comment: @GSerg seems like a great process. Have you tried it? If so it should be an accepted answer (so please write it as one?) because it's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I haven't and I have no idea if it's any good. That was the result of entering your question to Google.

Comment: This belongs on DBA but would be a duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174/23369 if migrated there.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it by using gunzip

You can export your data by using below command

```
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] | gzip -9 > [backupfile.sql.gz]
```

Do ftp whereever you want to do

To restore compressed backup files you can do the following:

```
gunzip < [backupfile.sql.gz] | mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname]
```